# Set Xcode preference setting "General|Mac Test Parallelization" and "General|Simulator Test Parallelization" to 'Max' from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcuitest

The setting in question:
[image]

I know about:

`xcodebuild 
-parallelizeTargets
-maximum-concurrent-test-device-destinations NUMBER 
-maximum-concurrent-test-simulator-destinations NUMBER
-parallel-testing-enabled YES|NO
-parallel-testing-worker-count NUMBER
-maximum-parallel-testing-workers NUMBER`

However, I would prefer not to have to query the system and get num cores and generate the desired setting using the commands above provided by Apple.

Since this setting is already achieved by Xcode, I'd just like to edit the appropriate Xcode plist with the correct key and value rather than come up with a nasty command line.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to automate my installation of Xcode with the desired settings above without human intervention and having to come up with a complicated command line interaction with `xcodebuild`.

Note: This appears to be an Xcode App preference, not something I can set on a per Workspace or Project setting via an `.xcconfig`

Answer (score 1):

After poking around, I found `com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`. We can use `plistbuddy` or `defaults` to set the flags. These values are not set in the plist if the user has never set the permission. The change is not persisted until the user quits an active Xcode, so automation may want to ensure Xcode is not running before attempting to modify this value..

The relevant plist keys are below:

```
$ defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist  | grep IDEMaxParallelTesting
    IDEMaxParallelTestingSimulators = 6;
    IDEMaxParallelTestingWorkersMac = 0;
```